# Implement redo keyboard shortcut tailored to specific OS

Tags: c++, gtkmm, gtkmm3

Suppose I want to distribute my application to all these three platforms:

1. Linux
2. Windows
3. OS X

Each system tends to have their own specific keyboard shortcuts standard, for instance, on Linux redo shortcut is `Ctrl + Shift + Z` whereas on Windows it's `Ctrl + Y`

I want my application to adapt to each environment so Linux shortcuts won't be active/compiled if it's run on OS X or Windows. And vice versa.

The solution I have in mind is using macros:

```cpp
#if __gnu_linux__
    application->set_accels_for_action("window.redo", "<Primary><Shift>Z");
#else
    // ...for all other platforms
    application->set_accels_for_action("window.redo", "<Primary>Y");
#endif
```

Is there a better way than using macros?

Comment: Are you aware of [QKeySequence](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#details)? Reading your question, I remembered that Redo should be one of the [standard sequences](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#StandardKey-enum), and it's in fact.

Comment: QKeySequence... no :( Checking it out :)